Android hydration tracker that can register defined fluid loss
I’m a plasma donor and currently use Waterllama on iOS to make sure I stay on top of hydration on and around the days I give plasma - specifically, the premium version has a feature where one can both define custom drinks and assign them hydration values, including negative values, so I register a donation as a “drink” with -100% hydration. However, I’m planning on switching to Android for my next phone and am now looking for an equivalent there. Specifically, what I’m looking for is a “pure” hydration tracker (that is, not a diet/journal/… app with a vestigial water tracker) with…

the ability to register a defined fluid loss in some way
the ability to use metric units
ideally, the ability to register different types of drinks with different hydration values
if possible, premium features as a one-time purchase rather than a subscription

An app with an iOS version would be preferable so I can try it out beforehand, but isn’t a must-have.
I’ve looked at WaterMinder, which also has customizable drinks, but from what I can find it doesn’t do “negative” hydration, which is the core thing I’m looking for.
